# Как можно провести линию между двумя блоками, если зажать мышь на одном и отпустить на другом?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

К примеру, между .span1 и .span2

```
<span class="span1">1</span>
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
<span class="span2">2</span>
```

Comment: вам именно через `dom` это нужно? потому что это больше извращение так линии рисовать. Лучше посмотреть в сторону `canvas`

Comment: хотя бы `svg`, все лучше чем рисовать DOMом

Comment: я еще рассматриваю вариант создания div с border-top 1px solid black и изменением его длинны и поворота при изменении положения курсора

Comment: я понимаю, но я веду к тому, что обычно такие вещи все таки делаются всякими `svg`шками, на `canvas`е, так как они больше предназначены для таких вещей

Comment: ну а по сути, не важно как, лишь бы получилось

Comment: элементы могут как угодно располагаться? или только вертикально/горизонтально?

Comment: значит гуглить использование svg?

Comment: как угодно можно

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Вот собрал что-то похожее из `svg`+`js`, вообще я обычно такое делаю на `d3.js`, тут ради исключения сделал на голом `js`, на `d3` листинг был бы не сильно длиннее, но все же лаконичнее...

Чтобы нарисовать прямоугольник, используйте перетаскивание левой кнопкой мыши на свободном месте.

Переместить прямоугольник можно так же перетаскиванием левой кнопкой.

Соединить прямоугольники можно при помощи перетаскивания правой кнопкой начиная на прямоугольнике

Двойное нажатие на прямоугольник позволяет добавить текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let x, y, shape, move, svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let attrs = (s, o) => Object.keys(o).forEach(p => s.setAttribute(p, o[p]))
let clampToCenter = e => [+e.getAttribute('x') + e.getAttribute('width')/2,
                          +e.getAttribute('y') + e.getAttribute('height')/2]
attrs(svg, {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight});

function startDrawLink(e) {
    shape = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    shape.source = e.target;
    let p = clampToCenter(e.target);
    attrs(shape,{x1: p[0], y1: p[1], x2: e.x, y2: e.y,
                 stroke: '#000', 'pointer-events': 'none'})
}

function startTranslateRect(e){
    move = e.target;
    move.px = +e.target.getAttribute('x');
    move.py = +e.target.getAttribute('y');
    move.ex = e.x;
    move.ey = e.y;
}

function translateRect(e) {
    attrs(move, {x: move.px + e.x - move.ex, y: move.py + e.y - move.ey})
    let p = clampToCenter(move);
    document.querySelectorAll('line').forEach(l => {
        let isSrc = l.source === move
        if (isSrc || l.target === move) {
            l.setAttribute(isSrc ? 'x1' : 'x2', p[0])
            l.setAttribute(isSrc ? 'y1' : 'y2', p[1])
        }
    })
    e.target.text && attrs(e.target.text, {
        x: move.px + e.x - move.ex + e.target.getAttribute('width')/2, 
        y: move.py + e.y - move.ey + e.target.getAttribute('height')/2
    })
}

function doDrawRect(e){
    attrs(shape, {
      x: Math.min(e.x, shape.cx), y: Math.min(e.y, shape.cy),
      width: Math.abs(e.x - shape.cx), height: Math.abs(e.y - shape.cy)
    })
}

function doDrawLine(e){
    if (e.target.nodeName === "rect" && e.target != shape.source) {
      let p = clampToCenter(e.target)
      attrs(shape, {x2: p[0], y2: p[1]})
      shape.removeAttribute('stroke-dasharray')
    } else {
      attrs(shape, {x2: e.x, y2: e.y, 'stroke-dasharray': '10 10'})       
    }
}

addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName === "rect") {
    if (e.button === 2) 
        startDrawLink(e)
    if (e.button === 0) 
      startTranslateRect(e);
    
  } else {
    shape = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
    shape.cx = e.x;
    shape.cy = e.y;
    attrs(shape, {fill: 'white', stroke: 'black'})
  }
  shape && svg.appendChild(shape);
})

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (move) 
      translateRect(e);
  if (shape) 
    if (shape.nodeName === "rect")
      doDrawRect(e);
    else  
      doDrawLine(e);
})

addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  if (shape && shape.nodeName === "line") {
    shape.remove();
    if (!shape.getAttribute('stroke-dasharray')) {
      svg.insertBefore(shape, svg.firstChild)
      shape.target = e.target;
    }
  }
  shape = null;
  move = null;
})

addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e.preventDefault())

addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.detail == 2 && e.target.nodeName === "rect") {
     if (!e.target.text) {
         e.target.text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
         let p = clampToCenter(e.target)
         attrs(e.target.text, {x: p[0], y: p[1], 'text-anchor': 'middle', 
                               'dominant-baseline': 'middle', 'pointer-events': 'none'})
         svg.appendChild(e.target.text);
     }
     e.target.text.innerHTML = prompt('enter text', e.target.text.innerHTML || '')
  }
})
```

```html
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden;user-select:none"><svg style="background-color: wheat"></svg>
```

——

UPD: [похожий ответ с использованием **d3.js**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014808/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-konva-js-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/1014927#1014927)

Comment: Отличный ответ, сейчас будешь 20.000 отмечать!

Comment: Эм.. А как теперь линию рисовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy правой кнопкой