# пользователь устанавливает связь объектов на холсте konva.js с помощью линий

Tags: javascript, svg, webix

Приложение на "Webix", которое должно графически отображать связи между входящими данными(input) которые проходят через некие фильтры и в конечном итоге должны быть соединены с выходом(output), внутри есть холст konva.js на нем расположены 5 квадратов и есть точки за которые пользователь может тянуть и образуя линии типа "quadratic Curve". 
Задача: Нужно чтобы пользователь мог с помощью этих линий образовывать связи между квадратами проводя через квадраты и привязывая квадрат к линии. Связи должны быть "многие ко многим", чтобы пользователь сам определял какое количество элементов и в каком порядке соединять. Сейчас я могу проводить , но не могу понять как привязать линию к квадрату. По хорошему нужно еще и отменять действие если вдруг пользователь установил не нужную ему связь, но я думаю , что можно это решить и просто очисткой холста с помощью кнопки reset, но тоже не могу ее соорудить.
Пожалуйста подскажите как я могу решить эти сложности, куда копать , где читать. Документацию по konve.js уже читал.

```js
webix.protoUI({
    name:"konva",
    $init:function(){
        this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: this.$view
        });
    },
    $setSize:function(x,y){
        if (webix.ui.view.prototype.$setSize.call(this, x,y)){
            //resize stage is view size was changed
            this.stage.size({ width:x, height:y });
        }
    },
    getStage:function(){
        return this.stage;
    }
}, webix.ui.view);

webix.ui({

    rows:[{
        cols:[{
        // template:"input"
        view:"form", id:"myForm", elements:[
                                            {
                                                view:"text",name:"input1",placeholder:"input-1", width:100
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input2",placeholder:"input-2"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input3",placeholder:"input-3"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input4",placeholder:"input-4"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input5",placeholder:"input-5"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input6",placeholder:"input-6"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input7",placeholder:"input-7"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input8",placeholder:"input-8"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input9",placeholder:"input-9"
                                            },{
                                                view:"text",name:"input10",placeholder:"input-10"
                                            }]
        },
//инициализируем холст konva.js
            { id:"k1", view:"konva" },
            { view:"resizer", drag:"move"},
            {},
            {view:"button", id:"reset", value: "Reset", width: 150, align:"center"},
            {
            template:"output"
            }],
    }]
});


// разметка холста в квадрат по 38px
var stage = $$("k1").getStage();

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    for (var ix = 0; ix < 20; ix++) {
        for (var iy = 0; iy < 20; iy++) {
            var box = new Konva.Rect({
                x : 40*ix+2,
                y : 40*iy+2,
                width : 38,
                height : 38,
                fill : 'darkgrey',
                stroke : 'white'
            });
            layer.add(box);
        }
    }
    layer.draw();
// отрисовываем квадраты которые могут двигаться по холсту
    var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 200,
        width: 68,
        height: 34,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect1);

      var rect2 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: 34,
        height: 34,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect2);

      var rect3 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 50,
        width: 34,
        height: 34,
        fill: 'black',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect3);

      var rect4 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 150,
        width: 34,
        height: 34,
        fill: 'orange',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect4);

      var rect5 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 250,
        width: 34,
        height: 34,
        fill: 'blue',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect5);

      // add cursor styling
      box.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });
      box.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      });

      layer.add(box);
      stage.add(layer);

var curveLayer, lineLayer, anchorLayer, quad, quad1, quad2;

      function updateDottedLines() {
        var q = quad;
        var q1 = quad1;
        var q2 = quad2;
        // var b = bezier;

        var quadLine = lineLayer.findOne('#quadLine');
        var quadLine1 = lineLayer.findOne('#quadLine1');
        var quadLine2 = lineLayer.findOne('#quadLine2');
        // var bezierLine = lineLayer.findOne('#bezierLine');

        quadLine.points([
          q.start.attrs.x,
          q.start.attrs.y,
          q.control1.attrs.x,
          q.control1.attrs.y,
          q.control2.attrs.x,
          q.control2.attrs.y,
          q.control3.attrs.x,
          q.control3.attrs.y,
          q.end.attrs.x,
          q.end.attrs.y
        ]);

        quadLine1.points([
          q1.start.attrs.x,
          q1.start.attrs.y,
          q1.control.attrs.x,
          q1.control.attrs.y,
          q1.end.attrs.x,
          q1.end.attrs.y
        ]);

        quadLine2.points([
          q2.start.attrs.x,
          q2.start.attrs.y,
          q2.control1.attrs.x,
          q2.control1.attrs.y,
          q2.control2.attrs.x,
          q2.control2.attrs.y,
          q2.control3.attrs.x,
          q2.control3.attrs.y,
          q2.end.attrs.x,
          q2.end.attrs.y
        ]);
        // bezierLine.points([
        //   b.start.attrs.x,
        //   b.start.attrs.y,
        //   b.control1.attrs.x,
        //   b.control1.attrs.y,
        //   b.control2.attrs.x,
        //   b.control2.attrs.y,
        //   b.end.attrs.x,
        //   b.end.attrs.y
        // ]);
        lineLayer.draw();
    }


      function buildAnchor(x, y) {
        var anchor = new Konva.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          radius: 5,
          stroke: '#666',
          fill: '#ddd',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          draggable: true
        });

        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          this.strokeWidth(2);
          anchorLayer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          this.strokeWidth(2);
          anchorLayer.draw();
        });

        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
          drawCurves();
          updateDottedLines();
        });

        anchorLayer.add(anchor);
        return anchor;

      }

      function drawCurves() {
        var context = curveLayer.getContext();

        context.clear();

        // draw quad
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(quad.start.attrs.x, quad.start.attrs.y);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(
          // quad.control.attrs.x,
          // quad.control.attrs.y,
          quad.end.attrs.x,
          quad.end.attrs.y
        );
        // context.setAttr('strokeStyle', 'red');
        // context.setAttr('lineWidth', 2);
        // context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(quad1.start.attrs.x, quad1.start.attrs.y);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(
          // quad1.control.attrs.x,
          // quad1.control.attrs.y,
          quad1.end.attrs.x,
          quad1.end.attrs.y
        );
        // context.setAttr('strokeStyle', 'orange');
        // context.setAttr('lineWidth', 2);
        // context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(quad2.start.attrs.x, quad2.start.attrs.y);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(
          // quad.control.attrs.x,
          // quad.control.attrs.y,
          quad2.end.attrs.x,
          quad2.end.attrs.y
        );

    }
        // draw bezier
        // context.beginPath();
        // context.moveTo(bezier.start.attrs.x, bezier.start.attrs.y);
        // context.bezierCurveTo(
        //   bezier.control1.attrs.x,
        //   bezier.control1.attrs.y,
        //   bezier.control2.attrs.x,
        //   bezier.control2.attrs.y,
        //   bezier.end.attrs.x,
        //   bezier.end.attrs.y
        // );
        // context.setAttr('strokeStyle', 'blue');
        // context.setAttr('lineWidth', 2);
        // context.stroke();




      // var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      //   container: 'container',
      //   width: width,
      //   height: height
      // });

      anchorLayer = new Konva.Layer();
      lineLayer = new Konva.Layer();

      // curveLayer just contains a canvas which is drawn
      // onto with the existing canvas API
      curveLayer = new Konva.Layer();

      var quadLine = new Konva.Line({
        dash: [5, 5, 0, 5],
        strokeWidth: 2,
        stroke: 'red',
        lineCap: 'round',
        id: 'quadLine',
        // opacity: 0.3,
        points: [0, 0]
      });

      var quadLine1 = new Konva.Line({
        dash: [5, 5, 0, 5],
        strokeWidth: 2,
        stroke: 'blue',
        lineCap: 'round',
        id: 'quadLine1',
        // opacity: 0.3,
        points: [0, 0]
      });

      var quadLine2 = new Konva.Line({
        dash: [5, 5, 0, 5],
        strokeWidth: 2,
        stroke: 'orange',
        lineCap: 'round',
        id: 'quadLine2',
        // opacity: 0.3,
        points: [0, 0]
      });

      // var bezierLine = new Konva.Line({
      //   dash: [10, 10, 0, 10],
      //   strokeWidth: 3,
      //   stroke: 'black',
      //   lineCap: 'round',
      //   id: 'bezierLine',
      //   opacity: 0.3,
      //   points: [0, 0]
      // });

      // add dotted line connectors
      lineLayer.add(quadLine);
      lineLayer.add(quadLine1);
      lineLayer.add(quadLine2);
      // lineLayer.add(bezierLine);

      quad = {
        start: buildAnchor(-5, 35),
        control1: buildAnchor(0, 35),
        control2: buildAnchor(0, 35),
        control3: buildAnchor(0, 35),
        end: buildAnchor(0, 35)
      };

      quad1 = {
        start: buildAnchor(-5, 70),
        control: buildAnchor(0, 70),
        end: buildAnchor(0, 70)
      };

      quad2 = {
        start: buildAnchor(-5, 105),
        control1: buildAnchor(0, 105),
        control2: buildAnchor(0, 105),
        control3: buildAnchor(0, 105),
        end: buildAnchor(0, 105)
      };

      // bezier = {
      //   start: buildAnchor(-10, 70),
      //   control1: buildAnchor(530, 40),
      //   control2: buildAnchor(480, 150),
      //   end: buildAnchor(300, 150)
      // };

      // keep curves insync with the lines
      anchorLayer.on('beforeDraw', function() {
        drawCurves();
        updateDottedLines();

        $('#reset').on('click', function(){
            lineLayer.reset();
        })
      });

      stage.add(curveLayer);
      stage.add(lineLayer);
      stage.add(anchorLayer);

      drawCurves();
      updateDottedLines();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.webix.com/components/edge/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> -->
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/4.0.4/konva.min.js" ></script >
    <style type="text/css">
      .mark{
        width:50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight:bold;
        float:right;
        background-color:#444;
        color:white;
        border-radius:3px;

        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var big_film_set = [{"id":1,"votes":"1",},{"id":2,"votes":"2"},{"id":3,"votes":"3"},{"id":4,"votes":"4"},{"id":5,"votes":"5"}];
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="konva.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: могу посоветовать-показать как сделать такое на svg + d3.js

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Буду рад увидит любой  подход, сейчас есть задача ее нужно решить все методы подойдут.

Comment: вечером соберу что то вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985185/188366

Comment: Это отличный пример

Comment: Спасибо!) Ты как всегда в точку, то что нужно

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Собрано при помощи svg+d3.js.

**UPD1:** Пример определения с какой стороны присоединять связь к блоку.

**UPD2:** За верх блока осуществляется перетаскивание, а за тело - создание связи. Вертикальные связи теперь тоже возможны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
    // массив с данными о блоках
const data = [[50,30], [90,130], [300,90], [550,10], [500,130]].map(rect),
    // массив с данными о связях между блоками
    links = [];

    // текущая создаваемая линия
let currentLink, 
    // текущий перетаскиваемый прямоугольник и его начальные координаты
    currentRect, x, y;

// фабрика горизонтальных связей 
var linkHorizontal = d3.linkHorizontal().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y);

// фабрика вертикальных связей 
var linkVertical = d3.linkVertical().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

// создаем прямоугольники
let rects = svg.selectAll("path.block")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .classed('block', true);

// вешаем слушатели на весь холст
svg.call(d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragstart)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("end", dragend));
  
d3.select(window)
    .on('resize', resize);

resize();
render();

function resize() {
  svg.attr('width', innerWidth)
    .attr('height', innerHeight);
}

// функция отрисовки
function render() {
    
  rects.attr("d", d => {
      let x = d.x, y = d.y, w = x + d.width, h = y + d.height, h4 = y + 16;
      return 'M' + [[x,y],[x,h],[w,h],[w,y],[x,y],[x,h4],[w,h4]].join('L');
  });

  let paths = svg.selectAll('path.link')
                 .data(links);  
    
  paths.exit()
       .remove();
    
  paths = paths.enter()
               .append('path')
               .classed('link', true)
               .merge(paths);
    
  paths.attr('d', createLink)
       .attr('stroke-dasharray', d => d.target.width ? '0' : '5 5');
}

// обработчик события drag
function dragged(e) {
  if (currentLink) {
    currentLink.target.x = d3.event.x;
    currentLink.target.y = d3.event.y;
    render();
  } else if (currentRect) {
    currentRect.datum().x = d3.event.x + x;
    currentRect.datum().y = d3.event.y + y;
    render();
  }
}

// обработчик начала перетаскивания
function dragstart() {
  let el = d3.select(d3.event.sourceEvent.target);
  let d = el.datum();
  if (!d) return;
  if (Math.abs(d.y - d3.event.y) > 16) {
    currentLink = {source: d, target: {x: d3.event.x, y: d3.event.y}};
    links.push(currentLink);
  } else {
    currentRect = el.raise();
    x = el.datum().x - d3.event.x;
    y = el.datum().y - d3.event.y;
  }
  render();
}

// обработчик окончания перетаскивания
function dragend(){
  currentRect = null;
  if (!currentLink)
    return;
  let d = d3.select(d3.event.sourceEvent.target).datum();
  if (!d) 
    links.pop();
  else
    currentLink.target = d;
  currentLink = null;
  render();
}

// логика определения точки привязки к блоку
function anchorPoint(self, opposite) {
    var x = (self.width||0)/2;
    var y = (self.height||0)/2;
    let horiz;
    if (self.width) {
        let dx = opposite.x + (opposite.width||0)/2 - self.x - x;
        let dy = opposite.y + (opposite.height||0)/2 - self.y - y;
        if (horiz = Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy))
            x = dx < 0 ? 0 : self.width;
        else
            y = dy < 0 ? 0 : self.height;
    }
    return {x: x + self.x, y: y + self.y, horiz};
}

// создает связь
function createLink(d){
    let data = {
        source: anchorPoint(d.source, d.target),
        target: anchorPoint(d.target, d.source)
    };
    let horiz = data.source.horiz || data.target.horiz;
    return horiz ? linkHorizontal(data) : linkVertical(data);
}

function rect(el) {
  return {x: el[0], y: el[1], width: 100, height: 60};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: wheat;
}

path.block {
  fill: white;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

path.link{
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
```

—-

PS: [похожий ответ на чистом javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985185/188366)

Comment: нормально получилось  cool :))

Comment: @Stranger in the Q А я как-то пропустил этот топик. Круто! Благодарю

Answer (score 4):

Решил поделится решением, надеюсь оно будет полезно всем кто найдет его. Огромное спасибо @Stranger in the Q за то, что всегда так быстро отвечает и подкинул идею по реализации. 
Управление осуществляется обычными командами клавиш с клавиатуру ctrl+z(действие отменить) ctrl+y(применить обратно отмененное действие), ctrl+c(скопировать объект), ctrl+v(вставить объект).На Konva.js я не смог решить эту задачу и поэтому прибегнул к другим библиотекам остановился на GOjs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.webix.com/components/edge/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/2.0.15/go-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .my_style: {
      background-color: aqua;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width=500px; height:500px; background-color:gray;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // webix.ui({
    //   views:'container',
    //   id:"myDiagramDiv",
    //   width:400,
    //   height:150,
    //   css:"my_style"
    // });

    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    diagram = $(go.Diagram, 'myDiagramDiv', {
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true
    });

    diagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Spot",
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
            fill: 'lightblue',
            width: 100,
            height: 50
          }),
          $(go.TextBlock, {
              margin: 10
            },
            new go.Binding("text", "key")
          )
        ),
        $(go.Panel, "Vertical", {
            alignment: go.Spot.Right
          },
          new go.Binding("itemArray", "portsI"), {
            itemTemplate: $(go.Panel, {
                portId: "",
                fromSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                fromLinkable: true
              },
              new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),

              $(go.Shape, "Ellipse", {
                  desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
                  fill: "green"
                },
                new go.Binding("fill", "color")
              )
            )
          }
        ),

        $(go.Panel, "Vertical", {
            alignment: go.Spot.Left
          },
          new go.Binding("itemArray", "portsBL"), {
            itemTemplate: $(go.Panel, {
                portId: "",
                fromSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                toLinkable: true
              },
              new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),

              $(go.Shape, "Ellipse", {
                  desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
                  fill: "green"
                },
                new go.Binding("fill", "color")
              )
            )
          }
        ),

        $(go.Panel, "Vertical", {
            alignment: go.Spot.Right
          },
          new go.Binding("itemArray", "portsBR"), {
            itemTemplate: $(go.Panel, {
                portId: "",
                fromSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                fromLinkable: true
              },
              new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),

              $(go.Shape, "Ellipse", {
                  desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
                  fill: "green"
                },
                new go.Binding("fill", "color")
              )
            )
          }
        ),

        $(go.Panel, "Vertical", {
            alignment: go.Spot.Left
          },
          new go.Binding("itemArray", "portsO"), {
            itemTemplate: $(go.Panel, {
                portId: "",
                fromSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                toLinkable: true,
                toMaxLinks: 1,
              },
              new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),

              $(go.Shape, "Ellipse", {
                  desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
                  fill: "green"
                },
                new go.Binding("fill", "color")
              )
            )
          }
        )


      );

    diagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link, {
          routing: go.Link.Orthogonal,
          corner: 3
        }, {
          routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes
        },
        $(go.Shape),
        $(go.Shape, {
          toArrow: "Standard"
        })
      );

    diagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel();
    diagram.model.linkFromPortIdProperty = "fromPort";
    diagram.model.linkToPortIdProperty = "toPort";
    diagram.model.nodeDataArray = [{
        key: "Input",
        portsI: [{
          portId: "Inputleft",
          color: "red"
        }]
      },
      {
        key: "Block",
        portsBL: [{
          portId: "Blockleft",
          color: "black"
        }],
        portsBR: [{
          portId: "Blockright",
          color: "purple"
        }]
      },
      {
        key: "Output",
        portsO: [{
          portId: "Outputleft",
          color: "green"
        }]
      }

    ];
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```