# Как реализовать подобный интерфейс?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Необходимо реализовать такую задумку. Есть некая рабочая область. В нее можно добавлять блоки, можно перемещать блоки. Должна быть возможность соединять блоки в цепочки. Все это должно делаться интерактивно. Например как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985185/188366

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1014927/188366

Comment: У меня на гитхабе есть похожая схема, я что-то пытался такое сделать, но забросил. Можешь посмотреть и забрать себе

Comment: @Doofy скинь ссылку пожалуйста

Comment: @xakslim у меня в профиле ссылки все. Репозиторий Nodes называется. Там только интерфейс, да и с кривыми базье я не закончил, придётся тебе самому строгать