# Создание линии между двумя объектами ( изображениями ) HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть файл HTML

```
<div> 
<img src="1.jpg" id="img1"> 
<img src="2.jpg" id="img2"> 
</div>
```

Как найти координаты x,y изображений на сайте с помощью JavaScript и провести между ними линию ?

Comment: линию между центрами?

Comment: Без разницы, хочу чтобы между объектами проходила линия, желательно конечно от края объекта до края следующего и если есть возможность сделать чтобы линия рисовалась постепенно, такое реально сделать?

Comment: да, конечно, изображений только 2?

Comment: Нет, всего их будет 9 , но линии будут расходится от определенных изображенний до других определенных ( древовидная система ). Мне хочется понять как это сделать а дальше самому стараться всё добавить, я предполагал делать через канвас, но тоже оказалось проблемой.
Так же я даже не могу понять как найти координаты точек, что является проблемой для старта

Comment: лучше бы конечно добавить изображение в вопрос. в целом поможет нечто такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985185/188366 попозже добавлю ответ

Comment: Там всё немного сложнее, мне нужно знать как найти крайние точки (x,y ) изображения 1 до ближайшей точки изображения 2 (x2, y2) и как провести между ними прямую

Comment: @voytenkodev `target.getBoundingClientRect()` то, что вы хотите называется координаты https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates

Comment: @voytenkodev воспользуйтесь svg или canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотели что-то типа такого?) Как я к этому пришёл - [ссылка на мой ответ на мой вопрос как рисовать линию по двум точкам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1068592/331312)
Вы задали ваш вопрос и я решил это сделать, это оказалось не просто, я вспомнил тригонометрию :D
Если вы хотите сохранить свои нервы в порядке - сделайте это на canvas, там всё намного проще. Просто указываете две точки и между ними рисуется линия.

Поясню свой код:
Функция `elemPosition` возвращает значение, где находится элемент на странице, даже если странница проскроллена, эта фунция вернёт позиции элемента относительно левого края документа и верхнего края документа

```js
function elemPosition(elem) {
    let pos = {
        top: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        left: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        right: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
        bottom: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
    };
    return pos;
}
```

Функция `centerElem` возвращает центр элемента по `x` и по `у`

```js
function centerElem(elem) {
    let width = elem.offsetWidth;
    let height = elem.offsetHeight;
    let centerX = width/2 + elemPosition(elem).left;
    let centerY = height/2 + elemPosition(elem).top;
    let pos = {
        y: centerY,
        x: centerX
    };
    return pos;
}
```

Функция `createPath` создаёт элемент-линию и анимирует её

```js
function createPath(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex) {

    let child = whatElems(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex);
    let childFrom = child.from;
    let childTo = child.to;
    render(childFrom, childTo);

}
```

Функция `whatElems` возвращает, какие элементы выбрать для анимации у родителя

```js
function whatElems(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex) {
    let child = {
        from : from.children[fromIndex],
        to : to.children[toIndex]
    }
    return child;
}
```

Функция `createDiv` создаёт `div` с классом `.harmony`, добавляет его в конец `body` и возвращает этот `div`, чтобы элементом можно было манипулировать сразу, после вызова этой функции

```js
function createDiv() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('harmony');
    document.body.append(div);
    return div;
}
```

Функция `createPathandPush` создаёт элемент и анимирует с помощью createPath, а также добавляет элемент в массив `paths`, чтобы каждым элементом потом можно было манипулировать

```js
function createPathAndPush(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex) {
    createPath(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex);
    paths.push([from, fromIndex, to, toIndex]);
}
```

Слушатель события `load`(загрузки изображений) вызывает срабатывание `createPathAndPush` для элементов через циклы, а также после циклов в глобальную переменную `harmonies` заносит все элементы, которые мы создали на странице
Функция `render` рендерит элемент и делает вычисления для точек, высоты, углов, на которые поворачивает. Если у функции `render` третий аргумент равен `undefined`, то она создаёт элемент и анимирует его, если передался третий аргумент, то функция просто ресайзит его, меняя у него угол поворота, длину и местоположение исходных точек
Если что непонятно - пишите, отвечу
P.S.: при клике по странице анимация начинается заново

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame       ||
           mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
           webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
           msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})();

function animate({timing, draw, duration, active}) {

  let start = performance.now();

  reqAnimFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction изменяется от 0 до 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // вычисление текущего состояния анимации
    let progress = timing(timeFraction);

    draw(progress); // отрисовать её

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}

function elemPosition(elem) {
 let pos = {
     top: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
     left: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
     right: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
     bottom: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
 };
 return pos;
}

function centerElem(elem) {
 let width = elem.offsetWidth;
 let height = elem.offsetHeight;
 let centerX = width/2 + elemPosition(elem).left;
 let centerY = height/2 + elemPosition(elem).top;
 let pos = {
  y: centerY,
  x: centerX
 };
 return pos;
}

function whatElems(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex) {
 let child = {
  from : from.children[fromIndex],
  to : to.children[toIndex]
 }
 return child;
}

function createDiv() {
 let div = document.createElement('div');
 div.classList.add('harmony');
 document.body.append(div);
 return div;
}

function render(childF, childT, elemResize, j) {

 let div = elemResize;

 if (elemResize == undefined) {
  div = createDiv();
 }


 let height = window.getComputedStyle(div, null).height; // исходная высота прямой
 height = Number(height.slice(0, height.length-2)); // исходная высота прямой
 let d, tang, arctg, angle, scale, final, start;

 function logic() {

  final = {
   x: centerElem(childT).x,
   y: elemPosition(childT).top
  }; // координаты конечной точки

  start = {
   x: centerElem(childF).x,
   y: elemPosition(childF).bottom
  }; // координаты начальной точки

  d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((final.x - start.x), 2) + Math.pow((final.y - start.y), 2) ); // длина прямой после анимации
  tang = (final.y-start.y) / (final.x-start.x)// Тангенс
  arctg = Math.atan(tang); // Арктангенс
  angle = arctg * 180 / Math.PI; // угол в градусах
  scale = d/height; // насколько масштабировать прямую по высоте

  if (tang < 0) {
   angle = 90 + angle;
  } else if (tang > 0) {
   angle = -(90-angle);
  }

 }

 logic();

 if (elemResize !== undefined) {

  if (progressGlobal[j+1] == 1) {
   reqAnimFrame(startResize);
  }

  function startResize() {
   div.style.transform = `translate(${start.x}px, ${start.y}px) rotate(${angle}deg) scale(1, ${scale}) translateZ(0)`;
  }
 } else {
  animate({
   duration: 5000,
   timing(timeFraction) {
    return timeFraction;
   },
   draw(progress) {
    logic();
    div.style.transform = `translate(${start.x}px, ${start.y}px) rotate(${angle}deg) scale(1, ${progress*scale}) translateZ(0)`;
    progressGlobal[j] = progress;
   }
  });

 }

}

function createPath(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex, j) {

 let child = whatElems(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex);
 let childFrom = child.from;
 let childTo = child.to;
 render(childFrom, childTo, undefined, j);

}

let progressGlobal = [];
let harmonies;
let paths = [];

function startHell() {

 function createPathAndPush(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex, j) {
  createPath(from, fromIndex, to, toIndex, j);
  paths.push([from, fromIndex, to, toIndex, j]);
  j++;
  return j;
 }

 let j = 0;

 for (let i = 3; i <= 5; i++) {
  j = createPathAndPush(items[i-3], 0, items[i], 1, j);
  j = createPathAndPush(items[i-3], 0, items[i], 0, j);
 }

 for (let i = 6; i <= 8; i++) {
  j = createPathAndPush(items[i-3], 0, items[i], 0, j);
  j = createPathAndPush(items[i-3], 0, items[i], 1, j);
  j = createPathAndPush(items[i-3], 1, items[i], 1, j);
  j = createPathAndPush(items[i-3], 1, items[i], 2, j);
 }

 harmonies = document.querySelectorAll('.harmony');

 for (let i = 0; i < harmonies.length; i++) {
  progressGlobal[i] = 0;
 }

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 startHell();
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
 for (let i = 0; i < harmonies.length; i++) {
  let child = whatElems(paths[i][0], paths[i][1], paths[i][2], paths[i][3]);
  let childFrom = child.from;
  let childTo = child.to;
  render(childFrom, childTo, harmonies[i], i-1);
 }
});

window.addEventListener('click', () => {

 for (let i = 0; i < harmonies.length; i++) {
  harmonies[i].remove();
 }

 startHell();

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.line:not(:first-child) {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 2%;
}

.item__img {
 z-index: 2;
}

.item__img:not(:first-child) {
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.line {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.harmony {
 z-index: 3;
 position: absolute;
 width: 2.5px;
 background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 transform: translateZ(0);
 transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="line line__one">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__one -->

 <div class="line line__two">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__two -->

 <div class="line line__three">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__three -->


</div> <!-- .wrapper -->

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```